# How subjective may be an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

This situation may happen. The context : ok I see your question but also I see where you are going and the question is not the point... the point is : take another approach (many beginer questions).

But surely, it is subjective to "know" or "understand" that the OP needs this kind of answer.

How to behave in this kind of situation ? Giving a "two level answer" (answering directly and also give another direction) ?

Example : boolean modifier usage and its consequences concerning ngons, edges loops, subsurf modifier, ...

Related : [When should an opinion based question be flagged?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/when-should-an-opinion-based-question-be-flagged/1118?noredirect=1#comment4643_1118)

Comment: In this situation I usually ask in the comments what the user is really trying to achieve. Are you actually doing X or are you really trying to do more common task Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/238438).

While the true nature of the OP's question may be a matter of opinion, that's certainly not what the OP is asking about. In other words, a question asking about solving a broken solution is not inherently an opinion-based question.

If you suspect the OP is trying to solve something other than what they're asking, I'd suggest leaving a comment asking for clarification. Perhaps even include a link to the [meta.se question linked above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/238438).

Comment: thanks. So an answer formulated like this can be ok ? "here is the answer of your question <... the direct answer...> but if I was you I dont do that because <... the arguments...>

Comment: @lemon Absolutely, I don't see anything wrong with that